# Show mysql data in html select tag

Tags: php, html, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Populate a Drop down box from a mySQL table in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189662/populate-a-drop-down-box-from-a-mysql-table-in-php)

I'm new to PHP/mySQL, but I'm learning it. I'm just creating a simple script to learn about mySQL, retrieving data from the database etc. I'm stuck on something, I hope you guys can help me!

I want to show the data of table 'leerlingen' in a html form, in the 'select' html tag. Each value has to has its own option tag, so like this:

```
  <select>
    <option value="VALUE 1">VALUE 1</option>
    <option value="VALUE 2">VALUE 2</option>
    <option value="VALUE 3">VALUE 3</option>
    <option value="VALUE 4">VALUE 4</option>
  </select>
```

I've searched a lot at Google, tried many things, but nothing seems to work..

Thanks!

Jelle

Comment: Doing the following google search "php mysql select" yielded an example in the first result for doing what you want: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+mysql+select&aq=f&oq=php+mysql+select&aqs=chrome.0.57j5j60j0l2j62.5620&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear you need to write a `foreach` loop to parse through each database row you have from your query.  Example below (result as an multidimensional array):

```
<select>
<?php
    foreach($rowset as $row) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['value'].'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: There's just one problem now: the data isn't inserted to the table in the database.. The other fields are inserted, so that part of the code is allright I guess..