# PHP - How do you get the values of a dropdown from SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Say I've got a dropdown list on my site like this:

```
<select>
<option value="test">Volvo</option>
<option value="icles">Saab</option>
<option value="lol">Mercedes</option>
<option value="hax">Audi</option>
</select>
```

But I don't want the above values, what if I want to get the values from an SQL table, how would I do this? Obviously this would be PHP but could someone give me an example?

Comment: You need to extract those key => value pair from a table, and then simply use `foreach` to display them

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populate a Drop down box from a mySQL table in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189662/populate-a-drop-down-box-from-a-mysql-table-in-php)

Comment: If this is a drop-down list, then what is this `ul > li > ul > li`?

Comment: @bad_boy where do you see those? :-O

Comment: @Ares There are jquery plugins for so-called drop-down lists, and those drop-down lists look consists of `ul > li`, not of selectbox.

Comment: @bad_boy ow... I see what you mean now... I thought you saw them in the OP's question :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to do it like this:

first select the values:

`$result = "SELECT * from table";`

then you will have to `foreach()` those values and create your selectbox like this:

```
echo '<select>';
foreach($result as $res) {
   echo '<option value="'.$res['somevalue'].'">' . $res['car_name'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

and you're done :D

Comment: In your code, $result is a string. You can't use it in a foreach()

Comment: You could be more cool, and do not print html tags, like `<select><?php foreach($data as $key => $val): ?><option>...</option><?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: @user3092432 you were downvoted by other users because you did not post something that you have tried... there are some rules on how to post. Please accept answer if it indeed helped you

Comment: @Adelphia the user did not specifically asked for that, I just gave him a really STANDARD example ;)

Comment: @Ares user can't downvote because it requires at least 125 reputation

Comment: @bad_boy I was talking about other users who downvoted his question

Comment: @Adelphia in your answer you provide a PDO example... how do you know he uses PDO? Maybe he uses mysqli... or better yet, mysql function... Is this why you got downvoted?

Comment: plus... broken code? That is not a code at all... who would name the table `"table"` and column `"somevalue"`? Jeez... it is JUST an example, not working code

Comment: @Adelphia I didn't donwvote you ;) sorry but that is not mine

Comment: @user3092432 please accept this answer if it helped you, or Adelphia's answer so we can get this over with. Thank you!