# Search Two Tables & Concatenate Answer

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to search two tables, match the results and then concatenate the answer...  Only finding results >= today's date.   This will then give the user the option to delete the selected from the DB.  So...

Table 1 called Prog_name

- id         prog_name
- 1          Breakfast
- 2          Mid Morning
- 3          Afternoon

Table 2 called talk_ups

- id         date_tx        prog_name    (prog_name value = prog_name.id)
- 1          2017-06-30     2
- 2          2017-07-03     1
- 3          2017-07-01     3

The result I am after is something like:  "01-07-2017, Afternoon".  But I do also need the talk_ups.id to ensure it only deletes the correct record.

I managed to figure out how to get the name to match the talk_ups.prog_name value:

```
'$sql. = "SELECT talk_ups.prog_name, prog_name.id as progID, prog_name.prog_name as theName FROM prog_name, talk_ups WHERE talk_ups.prog_name = prog_name.id";'
```

But I can't figure out how to do the two searches and end up with the right result and how to separate out the results to then concatenate them.

Comment: One code line, one syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JOIN` with `WHERE` condition, e.g.:

```
SELECT pn.id, pn.prog_name, tu.date_tx
FROM prog_name pn JOIN talk_ups tu ON pn.id = tu.prog_name
WHERE tu.date_tx > NOW();
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for that.  How does the result appear so I can put that into a dropdown list?  This is the version (and yes I know it's wrong) I have at the moment, how do I need to adjust it?  `$result = mysqli->query($sql);
        
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo "<OPTION value='" .$row['id'] ."'>" .$row['prog_del'] ."</OPTION>";`

Comment: Wrap the query into php code as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189662/populate-a-drop-down-box-from-a-mysql-table-in-php)?

Comment: I apologise for my dumbness, so it's currently set up like this:  `<SELECT name='talkup_del'>
 <OPTION value=''>Select
 </OPTION>
<?php    
 $sql = "SELECT prog_name.id, prog_name.prog_name, talk_up.date_tx FROM prog_name prog_name JOIN talk_ups talk_up ON prog_name.id = talk_up.prog_name WHERE talk_up.date_tx > NOW()";
            
$result = mysql_query($sql);
      
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<option value='" . $row['talk_up.prog_name'] . "'>" . $row['talk_up.prog_name'] . "</option>";
     }
?></SELECT>`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I can't seem to get it to do anything helpful.

Comment: @JonTalbot can you add these details into the question?